# If statement reference multiple cells with strings

Tags: excel

I have equation If(A1=c1:c10),1,0)).
The cell range C1:C10 are cells that each contain an individual string (so cell c1 = 'word1', c2 = 'word2' etc.
I want to see if A1 matches any of these. This equation doesn't work for strings, so was hoping to get some pointers  on this.

Comment: What you want to check - if A1 equal to one then values in  c1:c10 range? or if it equal to all cells together in c1:c10 range?
Can you share screenshot with sample data?

Comment: For better clarification you should include few sample data and desired output.

Comment: Are you asking if any of `C1:C10` are equal to `A1`? And are you saying that you don't have `C1:C10`, but you have `"C1:C10"` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try below formula-

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,$C$1:$C$10,0)),1,0)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question. The question is really quite unclear. I still don't see how this fits.

Comment: @Enigmativity This answer is good. It checks if there is **any** coincidence between the text in A1 and list of words in range C1:C10. OP said *I want to see if A1 matches any of these*

Answer (score 0):

[image]

*I want to see if A1 matches any of these*

You can count how many times the word in cell A1 appears in range C1:C10. IF the count is zero, it means there is no match, else there is 1 or more matches. Just use COUNTIF combined with IF in cell B1:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($C$1:$C$10;A1)=0;0;1)
```

Comment: Just remind OP that you use ";" on your system and they may need to replace with "," to match their system. And why the if(), if there are multiple matches then that gets hidden...

Comment: @SolarMike The IF is based on OP expected output. OP posted *If(A1=c1:c10),1,0))* so OP does not need to know how many matches, just want to know if there is a match or not